# Why does it take SO long to have edits reviewed?

Tags: discussion, edits, badges

So I've been working on a couple badges;

1. The archaeologist badge (edit 100 posts 6 mos. old or more)
2. 200 points in one day

Been doing so by using some searches like this:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/910482/archaeologist-for-node-js

editing the ones that need it, and then waiting for them to be reviewed and accepted (or not), since you only get to have x number of unreviewed edits before you can keep editing.

Problem is, it takes ***hours*** to get them reviewed, and when they do, they usually only review 2-3 at a time. So completely forget about getting 200 points a day *that* way, it won't happen; but also, it's just taking way longer than (it seems) it should to simply edit 100 posts.

Any idea why it takes so long just to review and accept/reject edits?

Comment: Why should it be quick?

Comment: @rene Why shouldn't it? You'd think naturally with the number of SO users alone it would be. Not to mention, efficiency; which I'm sure the owner(s) of SO would appreciate.

Comment: the [average to get a suggested edit handled is 2 hours](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1113713)

Comment: Protip for the 200 point in one day: write good questions and answers, a lot of them, and in a few month/years, each one getting a random upvote because it has been helpful will pile on to make you repcap multiple times per month

Comment: ^ can verify. The more posts you have, the more likely someone is to stumble over your post. There's millions of answers on SO after all.

Comment: Reviewing edits is not as easy as it seems. It often happens that people "improve typos" and break questions / snippets with that. It's also not the most rewarding task ...

Comment: But you aren't editing posts into shape in Triage. Often my reviews in Suggested Edits lead to me fixing a post either because a good edit didn't fix enough or because a bad suggestion was made to a post with glaring problems.

Answer (score 18):

It kind of depends on who you ask, but I'll offer up some (mostly random) reasons.

1. I have a full-time job which isn't reviewing things in the edited posts queue.
2. I have a few other obligations on the site, which don't pertain to looking at the edited posts queue.
3. I already have the gold badge for the edited posts queue, so I don't really see any incentive to go back there.
4. I've been review banned, or I *totally* would be reviewing edited posts.
5. I don't feel comfortable enough approving the edit(s) you made, because I lack the necessary expertise in the subject to objectively see whether or not you made a *good* edit.

In all honesty, I would think that you may be going a bit *quick*.  Edits should not be made *just* for the sake of getting a badge.  You should be making edits that add value and improve the post.

Alternate take:  some of your edits are getting rejected, which means that you're missing out on the rep (and slowly but surely bringing yourself to the attention of the automated ban scripts in place to curb some of this behavior).

So I would give you these two bits of advice:

## Be patient.

The reviews will happen in due time.  They don't decay.

## Be thorough.

If you're just making one or two letter changes, you're not helping.  If you're making sweeping prose changes, you're not helping.  The idea is for you to make improvements that matter, and that varies for each question.

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that participating in content curation on our sites is a volunteer process that requires users have the time and motivation to participate.

[image: 140 Suggested Edits waiting for review]

Currently there's 140 items waiting for review in the suggested edits queue, so even if your review only takes a few seconds to actually get approved, it's dropped in a big bucket and only a handful of people participating (or even aware of) review tasks. It takes as many as three (and as few as one) reviewers for each task and there's a limit to the number of reviews that can be completed each day.

The thing is, very little on our sites is super time sensitive, doubly so when it comes to edits that are on posts this old. You're doing curation that likely needs doing, but it's not pressing. Once you achieve the 2,000 reputation needed to edit directly, things will be much easier for you.

A final note, much of your time-based friction is likely due to your attempt to earn two badges that are, essentially, incompatible. You can only earn up to 1000 reputation for suggesting edits at all, can only have so many in queue at time, and you're dependent on others for those to be accepted so that you can get sufficient of them to reach that 200 rep in a single day.